# Simple dom to find out image url

Tags: html, dom, simpledom

I have an index.html code like this

```
<div class="photoImg">
<img src="http://host.com/images/image-name.jpg" alt="image" />
</div>
```

and I use this code to findout the image url (http://host.com/images/image-name.jpg)

```
    <?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "index.html";
echo $url;
foreach($html->find('div.photoImg') as $photo){
$item['src'] = $photo->find('img', 0)->src;
$photo[] = $item;
}
print_r($photo);
?>
```

But It doesn't work.
Can anyone help me fix my code !

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
$photodivs = $html->find('div.photoimg');
foreach($photodivs as $photo)
$images[] = $photo->find('img',0)->src;
var_dump($images);
```

Comment: it show "$image" only and i found the way to get the image..thank for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pass the `photoImg` class directly to the image?